# Can't dismiss alerts programmatically in Mac Catalyst?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, mac-catalyst

I'm showing an alert like this:

```
self.connectingAlert = [UIAlertController
    alertControllerWithTitle:@""
    message:NSLocalizedString(@"CONNECTING", nil)
    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[self.connectingAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction
    actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"BUTTON_CANCEL", nil)
    style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [self cancelRequest];
    }]];
[self presentViewController:self.connectingAlert animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

Then later I want to dismiss the alert programmatically like this:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:FALSE completion:nil];
```

The dismiss code works fine in iOS, but does nothing in Mac Catalyst. This might have something to do with the fact that alerts are presented as a part of the app window, sort of outside of the app, and the presentation style is ignored. But I would expect the dismiss method to still affect the Mac alerts.

I tried this to make sure everything is hooked up correctly:

```
UIViewController *test1 = self.connectingAlert.presentingViewController;
UIViewController *test2 = self.connectingAlert.presentingViewController.presentedViewController;
```

`test1` returns the navigation controller that the view controller is part of, which seems odd, but it does the same thing on iOS. `test2` returns my alert. Just to make sure, I tried this code, but it doesn't work either:

```
[self.connectingAlert.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:FALSE completion:nil];
```

Does anyone have experience with this? I don't see anything about it in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismissviewcontrolleranimated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that while you're supposed to send the dismiss message to the presenting (parent) view controller...

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:FALSE completion:nil];
```

...I have to send the dismiss message to the alert instead, and then it dismisses:

```
[self.connectingAlert dismissViewControllerAnimated:FALSE completion:nil];
```

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismissviewcontrolleranimated) for `dismissViewControllerAnimated` says:

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view
>   controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view
>   controller itself, UIKit asks the presenting view controller to handle
>   the dismissal.

I think what this means is that Mac Catalyst is doing something funny with the connection between the presenting and the presented view controller. If I check `self.presentedViewController`, that gives me the `UIAlertController`. But if I call `self dismiss dismissViewControllerAnimated...`, nothing happens, as if there is no presented view controller. But if I call `self.connectingAlert dismissViewControllerAnimated...`, the dismiss method somehow finds its way to the real presenting view controller. I'll report this as a bug to Apple.

Meanwhile, I'm happy to have a workaround.